# Using beeline with multi-line statements fails

Tags: hive

I'm try to migrate a command from hive cli to beeline:

```
$ hive -e "USE my_db;ALTER TABLE apache_log ADD PARTITION(year = 2015, month = 3) LOCATION 'hdfs://DB//user/my_db/prod/apache_log/2015/03';"
```

this works.

But when doing it in beeline it doesn't like the "USE my_db;" part:

```
$ beeline -u jdbc:hive2://my_server.com -n my_user -p my_password -e "USE my_db;ALTER TABLE apache_log ADD PARTITION(year = 2015, month = 3) LOCATION 'hdfs://DB/user/my_user/prod/apache_log/2015/03';"
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:9 missing EOF at ';' near 'my_db' (state=42000,code=40000)
Beeline version 0.12.0-cdh5.1.3 by Apache Hive
```

Based on the error message (expecting EOF) it seems to me that beeline would not accept multi-statements like hive cli used to do?

Answer (score 0):

I have raised it as a Hive bug and was accepted as a bug and patch provided: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9877

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this by doing it this way:

(i wrote it on more than one line to make it more readable)

```
beeline 
-u jdbc:hive2://my_server.com 
-n my_user -p my_password 
-e "USE my_db;"
-e "ALTER TABLE apache_log ADD PARTITION(year = 2015, month = 3) LOCATION 'hdfs://DB/user/my_user/prod/apache_log/2015/03';"
-e "--other nice queries..."
```